# Calling parameterized scalar function across servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to call a scalar function that resides on a whole different server. I know how to join in linked tables from different servers but made the presumption I could do the same with scalar functions. Can you even? Both servers are 2008. If I need to configure for RPC what are the consequences of that, if any? Thanks.

Through trying different combinations I've gotten the messages:

Invalid column name 'MSPSQL2\MSPSQL3'.
Server 'MSPSQL2\MSPSQL3' is not configured for RPC.

I won't post the whole procedure as it is largish but here is the relevant part:

```
   Select....
   CASE 
   WHEN P.DocketNumber IS NULL AND T.DocketNumber IS NOT NULL 
   THEN  [MSPSQL2\MSPSQL3].IPMaster.dbo.TMRemarks(T.TrademarkMasterID) --ISNULL(TText.Text, '') 
   WHEN P.DocketNumber IS NOT NULL AND T.DocketNumber IS NULL 
   THEN ISNULL(PText.Text, '') ELSE '' 
   END AS DocketingRemarks

   From...
```

Comment: Did you consider copying the function over to the current server, or is that not an option?

Comment: Have you added a link for the remote server?  (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479(v=sql.110).aspx.)

Comment: Dave: The function resides on another server as it draws data from tables on that remote server.


Gordon: Yes, the same server is linked in and I'm already using it to join in tables.